# Can I use SVGs instead of PNGs to large scale project

Tags: android, ios, svg, vector, png

We've already built projects like [DocuSign](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/docusign-upload-sign-docs/id474990205) in both iOS and Android, we've quite extensive use of documents which is loaded in form of PNGs, where users can quickly move to their selected page (e.g 1 -> 25), so we worked on closely to make it stable and fast but we've requirement to not gets pixelated while zooming (where PNG lack and gets pixelated), so I done R&D on vector base supported in iOS and found that PDF will not fit for our requirement but SVG may fit. But As SVGs aren't natively supported in iOS so

- Is it the right decision to use any third party for SVG support in iOS
  like https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit in large scale projects?
- Will memory management will effect I read many links where it
  mentioned it's not recommended like
  https://www.quora.com/Should-you-use-SVG-files-for-images-in-an-iOS-app
  ?

Does anybody go through this kind of problem? looking for suggestions and solutions.

NOTE: These images are coming from cloud(our server, google drive, dropbox and One drive)

Comment: svgs are not supported natively on android too  . You have to convert to vector drawable

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vector xml

1. Right click on rec>drawable folder
2. select Vector Asset
3. then select Local file(SVG)
4. Pick path of svg file

and import this will convert your SVG to the vector xml file, this vector drawable you can use in place of PNG files

[image]

Comment: These images are coming from server

Comment: for this i'm using https://github.com/ar-android/AndroidSvgLoader this library